# Difference between SOAP and NuSOAP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am having difficulty understanding a process, in webService creation in php.

I've created a server that makes a following call:

```
<?php


require_once "lib/nusoap.php";

  $soap = new soap_server;

  $soap->configureWSDL('WS-WebCodeFree', 'http://localhost/ws-webcodefree/');

  $soap->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'http://soapinterop.org/xsd/';

    $soap->register(
        'info',
        array(),        
        array('x' => 'xsd:string'),
        'http://soapinterop.org/'
    );

$soap->service(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '');

function info(){
    return "WebCodeFree - Desenvolvimento Web.";
}
```

Client-side:

```
<?php
    include "lib/nusoap.php";

    $client =  new SoapClient('http://localhost/web-service/ws-webcodefree.php?wsdl');

    $result1 = $client->call('info');
```

I return the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("call")
>   is not a valid method for this service in
>   C:\GitHub\voxy\app\retorno\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\GitHub\voxy\app\retorno\index.php(3): SoapClient->__call('call',
>   Array) #1 C:\GitHub\voxy\app\retorno\index.php(3):
>   SoapClient->call('info') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\GitHub\voxy\app\retorno\index.php on line 3

I seem to have a conflict between nusoap and soap, so I read.

If I switch calls, to nusoap_client on the client call, it resolves.

But I really wanted to know where the problem is, and what the difference is between them.

Grateful.